# R Summation in Pivot Table

Tags: r, aggregate, pivot-table

I have a pivot table with 4 rows (Name, Grade, Subject, Marks).  have a unique combination, but marks can have different values (based on mid term marks, final marks, etc.). While making pivot table, I get records in separate rows like , , and so on. I want to aggregate marks at last level, and make output as  or  or . Last level should take care of aggregation of marks based on previous levels. Is there a way of doing this? [attaching an example here, where I want to aggregate marks at last level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlhtf.jpg)

Comment: Unclear, please show what your table looks like.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: If you are using an R library that makes such a display, then you should name it and produce code. If this is just an Excel question, you should remove the [r] tag, because there is a fair chance that you are just annoying R users with it.

Comment: @V_Gupta: Please respond to the comments and answers.

Answer (score 2):

The [pivottabler](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pivottabler/index.html) package can produce the table illustrated in the question.  (I'm the package author).

**Sample Data**

```
Name = c("Rahul", "Rahul", "Rahul", "Rahul", "Rahul", "Rahul", "Ram", "Ram", "Ram", "Ram")
Grade = c(10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 11, 11)
Subject = c("English", "Hindi", "English", "Hindi", "Maths", "Science", "English", "Hindi", "English", "Hindi")
Marks = c(90, 91, 72, 65, 90, 95, 90, 80, 83, 81)
Results = data.frame(Name, Grade, Subject, Marks)
```

**Listing each result separately**

```
library(pivottabler)
pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(Results)
pt$addRowDataGroups("Name")
pt$addRowDataGroups("Grade", addTotal=FALSE)
pt$addRowDataGroups("Subject", addTotal=FALSE)
pt$addRowDataGroups("Marks", addTotal=FALSE)
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="Totals", summariseExpression="n()")
pt # to output as plain text to console
pt$renderPivot() # to output as HTML table
```

[image]

**Showing the mean of results**

```
library(pivottabler)
pt <- PivotTable$new()
pt$addData(Results)
pt$addRowDataGroups("Name")
pt$addRowDataGroups("Grade", addTotal=FALSE)
pt$addRowDataGroups("Subject", addTotal=FALSE)
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="Mean", summariseExpression="mean(Marks)")
pt$defineCalculation(calculationName="Totals", summariseExpression="n()")
pt # to output as plain text to console
pt$renderPivot() # to output as HTML table
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't look exactly like the image but close. Perhaps embedded in some sort of web-targeted display panel?

Comment: I think the picture in the original post is from the rpivotTable package (or the javascript equivalent) where pivot tables are created by drag/drop, e.g. see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpivotTable/vignettes/rpivotTableIntroduction.html).  The pictures in my answer are the HTML output produced by the pivottabler package, as displayed in the "Viewer" pane in R Studio, though the HTML can be exported, either just using R Studio (e.g. clicking on the "Show In New Window" button on the "Viewer" pane) or by using pt$saveHtml().  Hope that clarifies.  Let me know if not

Comment: PS.  I interpreted the original question to mean "How can I produce data output that looks like this image?" so I was aiming for matching the structure and numbers rather than styling/formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use table

```
table(df$Name, df$Grade, df$Subject, df$Marks)
```

where df is your data frame